# Swing components in applet not working

Tags: java, swing, applet

When I add swing components to my applet, they don't show up. Sometimes if I move my mouse around some JButtons pop up(strange). I have a method paint(Graphics g){} and update(Graphics g){}, but even when I remove all the images and painting code, the components still don't appear. Is this something normal that happens with applets, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: Does your Applet extend JApplet? post some code for better answers

Comment: Verify that your applet is constructed on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for the proper way to code an applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Stupid mistake by me. I was using Applet, not JApplet.

Answer (score 1):

It's common not in applets, but also in Java program. As far as I know, I meet with many cases like that due to the incompatibility issue. When this thing happens, minimize a window and resize it and all the objects pop up as they should. I'm not sure whether there's a solution to that. I think there should be one. This mostly happens when you have objects overlapping.

EDIT: Information maybe useful: When a window is resized in a regular java program, javax.swing.JComponent.repaint() is called.

Comment: *"also in Java program."*  No it's not, not unless the code is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wrote a program using JFrame and Null Layout. This thing happens quite often when I have objects overlapping. The object that should be on top of another sometimes get covered. If you want I can post my codes somewhere else and I don't think my codes are fundamentally wrong.

Comment: *"..Null Layout"*  There is the source of the problem.  See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem, here is the solution that helped me:

In your paint(Graphics g) method to paint all containers properly use super.paint(g).

Like:

```
void paint(Graphics g)

{

  super.paint(g);

 //code to draw something 

}
```